# Render part of a view in middleware?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to have some after middleware so that if the request was ajax, only render part of the view. I'm having issues though.

My method in my controller:

```
$data = $this->repository->getUser($id);
$view = View::make('site.user')->withData($data);

return $view;
```

My middleware:

```
$response = $next($request);
if(Request::ajax()){
    $response->renderSections()['content'];
}

return $response;
```

I get the error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::renderSections()
```

Comment: `renderSections` is a function on `Illuminate\View\View`, not `Illuminate\Http\Response`.

Comment: Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the response you need to use a `after Middleware` which is you are doing now so, you have response as given below:

```
$response = $next($request);
```

Now you may try this:

```
$content = $response->getOriginalContent()->renderSections()['content']
```